# Align a circular border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-shapes

I am having difficulty aligning my circular border to the text above it, and centering the text within the circle. When I comment out the `width: 80px;` in my `.oval` class then it appears to be aligned however the circle is then distorted

[image]

```
<div class="container body-content">
    <div class="row tab-content">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Welcome, Admin</h1>
            <p class="lead">Please select one of the tabs above to begin</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row adminrow">
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
                <h4>Total Users</h4>
                <div class="oval">
                    <h4>100</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <h4>Unauthorized Users</h4>
                <div class="oval">
                    <h4>25</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <h4>Total Games</h4>
                <div class="oval">
                    <h4>0</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <h4>Games Played</h4>
                <div class="oval">
                    <h4>80</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <h4>Investigator Groups</h4>
                <div class="oval">
                    <h4>2</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My CSS class is as follows**

```
.tab-content {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 30px;
}

.jumbotron {
    text-align: center;
}

.adminrow {
    text-align: center;
}

.oval {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #000000;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: just add to `.oval` class `display:inline-block;`

Comment: There is fiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12174/ ... but, I have to remove all those `col-xs-2` classes and `row` class, and add `.adminrow > div`... You can see in fiddle example if that's ok for You.

Comment: @nelek thank you for this! But now I am trying to get the text to be centered within the circle (shifted down) how would I go about doing that?

Comment: There is new fiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12191/ ... You can keep `h4` but I add one more class `.oval h4`, where `display` set to `table-cell`, because You can align text vert. and horiz.. See fiddle example and You'll see if number is wider then circle, he will be wraped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would adding this do what you want ?

```
.oval {
    line-height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't he want both?

Comment: I read his question too quickly ^^ But nelek's answer does the trick for the other part.

Comment: `display:inline-block;` get's the circles centered but I cannot get the text to be centered within the circle (shifted down). `line-height: 80px;` isn't doing anything

Comment: What about this : `.oval h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 80px;
}`

Comment: it doesn't work. However, `h4{ line-height:50px }` seems to work pretty well. The only problem with it is that there is a decent gap between the header (i.e `Total Users`) and the oval with the number

Comment: `.oval {line-height: 80px;}` works when if I take the numbers out of the `<h4>` tags. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you just need to change the `display` property of circle:

```
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    // other properties
}
```